# Will Put method returns anything in REST, Working fine in POSTMAN interceptor

Tags: java, rest

I have following PUT method..
When i request from POSTMAN it returns correct result but when hit the URL in Chrome i am getting "HTTP ERROR 405"..
URL is like below
http://localhost:7001/RESTfulWS/university/emp/3/Abhi

```
@PUT
    @Path("/emp/{employeeid}/{employeename}")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String updateEmployeeName(@PathParam("employeeid") String empid,@PathParam("employeename") String ename){
        int a=0;
        try{  
                Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");  

                Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:ORCL","ABCD","ABCD");  

                Statement stmt=con.createStatement();  
                System.out.println("update employee set name='"+ename+"' where ID ="+empid+"");
                a=stmt.executeUpdate("update employee set name='"+ename+"' where ID ="+empid+"");
                System.out.println("Updated Successfully "+a);

            }catch(Exception e){ System.out.println(e);}
        if(a>0){
            return "Name updated for employee id"+empid+" is done ";
        }else{
            return "Some error happened";
        }

    }
```

Can anybody help

Comment: How exactly you send a PUT request from chrome? I do not think that it is possible.
Just copy-paste the url is not enough.

Comment: 405 is "method not allowed", so I assume you are pasting the url in the browser bar, which will do a GET request.

Comment: It's possible, but if you do it using JavaScript, by sending an AJAX request.

Comment: @JBNizet the old fashioned form submit also still works ;)

Comment: When you hit `http://localhost:7001/RESTfulWS/university/emp/3/Abhi` this url by default HTTP method is GET. That's why you are getting  `HTTP ERROR 405` it means "method not allowed".

Comment: Ohh okay will try AJAX request .. Thank you all